Is there a classification of simple complex Lie groups?
The classification of simple Lie groups is a famous solved problem in mathematics. Have simple complex Lie groups been classified? If not, how much is known about them? (by complex Lie group i mean complex manifolds with a group structure such that its operations are holomorphic).

I find it odd that you know the classification of simple (connected) Lie groups but not complex ones, which is easier. What books on Lie groups have you read?

The wikipedia page has many answers here.

@MoisheKohan I'm surprised if it is easier. Aren't there continuum many nonisomorphic complex tori?

Complex tori are not simple!

@QiaochuYuan Right, but it still seems surprising there aren't continuum many other simple ones since there are continuum many complex tori.

My understanding is that “simple” in this context is just defined to mean “the Lie algebra is simple,” so one reduces to 1) the well-understood and rigid classification of simple complex Lie algebras, and 2) a computation of the discrete subgroups of the centers of the simply connected groups. The centers should all be finite in this case. So the classification is rigid. Complex tori have moduli because of the freedom to choose how their (infinite) fundamental groups sit inside their universal covers.

@QiaochuYuan How does that relate with being simple in the sense of being connected and having no proper normal subgroups?

That definition is too restrictive, it only produces the adjoint forms, e.g. it doesn't include $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ because it has nontrivial center. Being simple in your sense (and nonabelian) implies the Lie algebra is simple (since a proper ideal of the Lie algebra would integrate to a normal subgroup); I think it's equivalent to (being nonabelian and) having no proper connected normal subgroups? In any case, either way the classification is rigid.

Just to formally answer this question. The classification of simple Lie groups usually starts with the complex ones. Well, it usually starts with classifying the complex simple Lie algebras as that is even easier.
In fact a complex Lie group is a real Lie group so you would have to classify them anyway.
The simple complex Lie algebras come in families $A_n, B_n, C_n, D_n$ as well as the exceptional ones $E_6, E_7, E_8, F_4, G_2$. Any simple Lie group has a Lie algebra from these.
For each Lie algebra, it has a unique simply connected Lie group and its other Lie groups are all quotients of that one by discrete subgroups of the centre. A simple Lie group has finite centre so this is only a finite list of groups and the quotient by the whole centre produces a group with trivial centre called the  adjoint group. I believe in the case of $E_8$ the simply connected group has no centre so is also the adjoint group.
The adjoint group is the only one that is simple as an abstract group since the centre is naturally a normal subgroup.
To classify real noncomplex Lie groups we then build on this by finding the real forms of our Lie algebras/groups. This gets a bit messier as some of the groups whose complex analogues are simply connected are not simply connected themselves. For example $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is not simply connected and we need to take an infinite cover of it to find the simply connected group.
You can find the full classification, including complex Lie groups (up to these quotients/covers) here.

I don't understand what you mean by the second paragraph. The morphisms of complex Lie groups are not the same as the ones of Lie groups. It would be like saying that to classify topological manifolds you'd need to classify smooth manifold, which is false: there are smooth manifolds that are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic. Given there are nonisomorphic complex tori of same dimension, i'm guessing the situation is same for complex Lie groups in general. Perhaps for simple complex Lie groups isomorphisms are the same as having isomorphic underlying Lie group?

@Carla_ Ah you are right, that is perhaps a subtle point although it is certainly true that two simple complex Lie groups which are isomorphic as real Lie groups will be isomorphic by holomorphism as well.
